# Can't update values in a nested list

Tags: python

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game for a class project. Basically I have this list:

```
grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I'd like to just update the list values with an X or an O depending on the player. I'm trying to do that with the following function where p is an integer that was input from the user (yes, I made sure the input was, in fact, an integer and not a string):

```
def place_sym(p):
    global turn
    global grid
    global plyr

    for r in grid:
        for c in r:
            if c == p:
                grid[r][c] = plyr[turn] # This is the line causing trouble.
```

When I run this code I get an error saying the list indices have to be integers and not list type. Alternatively, I tried simply replacing the variable c with this line instead of the `grid[r][c] = plyr[turn]`

```
c = plyr[turn]
```

Printing the value and type of c revealed c to be int, and match the value input by the user. So I can find the variable, and the type matches, I just can't update the value in the original list. Am I using the global variables incorrectly? I can't figure out why it will not update. Here is the whole program so far:

```
grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
plyr = ("X","O")
turn = 0

def drw_brd():
    i = 1
    f = turn
    for spc in grid:
        print " " + str(spc[0]) + " | " + str(spc[1]) + " | " + str(spc[2]) + " "
        if i<=2:
            print "-----------"
            i+=1

    print''
    print "Player %s (%s's) it's your turn!" %(str(f+1),plyr[turn])
    place = input('Cell number to take:')
    place_sym(int(place))
    check_win()

#def san_in(x):
#    if x not in range(1,9):
#        print "Please enter a number 1 through 9."

def check_win():
    switch_plyr()

def switch_plyr():
    global turn

    """
    if turn == 0:
        turn = 1
    else:
        turn = 0
    """
    if turn <= 0:
        turn = 1
    elif turn >= 1: 
        turn = 0

    #print turn
    drw_brd()

def place_sym(p):
    global turn
    global grid
    global plyr

    for r in grid:
        for c in r:
            if c == p:
                c = plyr[turn]
```

Comment: `grid[r][c] = plyr[turn]` => `r[c] = plyr[turn]` in `for c in r` => `for c,_ in enumerate(r)`, bar that: no need for a nested loop

Comment: I just gave that a shot but I got this error: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I'll try your edit

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of my code, you can print the variables when looping to see their type and what you're comparing.

Comment: so `place_sym` creates a "vertical" line right? in that case with only the outer loop: `r[p] = plyr[turn]`

Comment: No, place_sym replaces the value in the list that matches the player's input with an X or an O

Comment: so I don't get it `def place_sym(p):` has only 1 parameter, which is the index of the column. To place a symbol somewhere you need 2 coordinates.

Comment: p is not the index. p is an integer 1-9 that was input by the user. I'm taking the input, comparing it to the values in the lists, and when I find the value in the lists that matches the input (p) I want to overwrite that matching value in the list with an X or an O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop `r` and `c` are the row and column not their index. You need to keep track of the index to update the value. You can do this using the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
def place_sym(p):
    global turn
    global grid
    global plyr

    # row_index will be 0, 1 or 2 (the position in grid).
    # row is an array of 3 integers.
    for row_index, row in enumerate(grid):
        # column_index will be 0, 1, 2 (the position in the row)
        # column_value is the actual integer value to check against
        for column_index, column_value in enumerate(row):
            if column_value == p:
                grid[row_index][column_index] = plyr[turn]
```

Comment: how can `column` be equal to `p` when `p` is an integer and `column` is a list? That achieves nothing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `column` is an integer, `grid` is an array of 3 child arrays, first loop goes through each of those child arrays which are assigned to the variable `row`, second loop goes through each integer in that row assigns the integer to variable `column` and checks if it matches the players input.

Comment: ok, understood. But you're using a double loop to set one value when you could set it with one assignment. Furthermore, OP stated that `p` is between 1 and 9. that cannot work. Period.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre of course it works, `p` is between 1 and 9 inclusive, `column` can be an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive (the original values in `grid`), the string `'X'` or the string `'O'`, depending on what moves have been made before.

Comment: ok, my bad. I understand now, it's using the values not the indexes. ok. can you edit so I can retract my downvote?